# JQassistant commandline report task is not generating asciidoc html files

Tags: jqassistant

Love the idea behind this tool, but I'm struggling with the documentation.

I am trying to generate a report of jar files using the commandline.

When I run ./bin/jqassistant.sh:

- scan, I see the generated associated neo4j store
- analyze produces jqassistant/reports/jqassistant-report.xml
- report produces jqassistant-report.html

Now I'm trying to create asciidoc files as described here: https://101.jqassistant.org/generate-reports-about-structures-and-metrics/index.html

I've placed an index.adoc file in jqassistant folder, but I do not see any corresponding html files generated in jqassistant/reports/asciidoc/

I'm new to jqassistant, so it's possible I am missing a configuration step, but I have a suspicion the asciidoc-report plugin is not being loaded.

Is there clear documentation on all the parameters to pass to commandline, including any configuration files such as .jqassisant.yml?

I created a file jqassistant/index.adoc

```
:toc: left
= My Project

// tag::default[]
[[default]]
== jQAssistant Rules

This section describes that default rules that are executed during each build.
// end::default[]
```

I ran
/bin/jqassistant.sh analyze
/bin/jqasisstant.sh report

I expected to see a file in jqassistant/report/asciidoc/index.html

Comment: Does your Asciidoc document contain any rules? If yes, do you see jQAssistant reporting the execution of your concepts and constraints?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use the plugin for Maven?

Comment: I have numerous repos and I don't want to integrate jqassistant (at this moment) into all of those projects.  Since the commandline is provided, I want to use it.

For testing tho, I did setup a simple helloworld maven project and created an index.adoc under jqassistant and see the maven plugin flow does generate what I expected.

But I want to do the same thing via the commandline.

Snooping through the source code, I see tests using jqassitant.yml files to pass in additional information, but no examples for analyze tag.  Is there docs for the spec of this file?

Comment: I might have found the possible cause.  

I see in this repo that the default value for ruleDirectory in the asciiPlugin is set to null.  https://github.com/jqassistant-contrib/jqassistant-asciidoc-report-plugin/blob/1.7/src/main/java/org/jqassistant/contrib/plugin/asciidocreport/AsciidocReportPlugin.java#L63

Comment: I also see that when i run ./bin/jqassistant.sh report -p myvalues.props, the property object is being set properly in the commandline repo, but it's not being passed properly to the asciidoc plugin repo.  I haven't traced down where it's getting lost tho.

Comment: Sorry for my silence. Can you put your example project on Github or does it contain sensitive data?

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for your support thus far.  My code does contain sensitive data and also doesn't ultimately matter. I'm trying to import any jar file and create a report. I've created an example project here: github.com/pebbz/jqassistant-demo-report. Check out the latest commandline jar jqassistant.org/get-started, i'm using jqassistant-commandline-neo4jv3-1.12.0. I scan jqassistant's jar files. As you can see, the asciidoc report is not being generated. Hopefully it's a simple mistake on my side, but you can see it's generating the report/jqassistant-report.html, but asciidoc is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Finally achieved to have it working ... partially. I used the tutorial project mentioned in the question.

First, I used version 1.12.2 (latest v1), it's also the versions (even if direct link is to v1.11.1) that is linked by [JQA Get Started](https://jqassistant.org/get-started/)

Most plugins seems to be missing from [v2 core distribution](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.buschmais.jqassistant.cli%20AND%20a:jqassistant-commandline-distribution), maybe still in migration progress, it's best to stick to v1 for command line uses. one need additional configuration to re-enable them (in.jqassistant.yml file).

Then, after detailled reading of [User Manual](https://jqassistant.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.12.2/manual/index.html), I finally got what's wrong!!

rules directory doesn't default to same value in CLI and in MVN plugin.

so with the command line one can change the lookup directroy for rules as :

`jqassistant scan analyze -f java:classpath::target/classes -r jqassistant`

you can also copy the rules (index.adoc, module.adoc, report.adoc, ...) in the subfolder jqassistant/rules.

index.adoc is beeing processed. but there are still missing configurations. Indeed class diagram remains empty. It has to do with a missing concept in CLI that is matched against in module.adoc:

```
MATCH
  (:Main:Artifact)-....
```

unfortunately there is no :Main concept in the store. I thought it may require scanning jar file (with MainClass) but same thing when scanning the jar instead of classes folder.

Short asnwer there are differences between CLI and MVN in default configuration. And unfortunately documentation is not precise enough to know which configuration one should do to make CLI work as MVN plugin.